# Video Compression for uploading in firebase storage

Tags: android, video, compression, media-queries, firebase-storage

I'm trying to capture video and upload it in firebase storage. The video is uploading just fine but it's taking too much time to upload. I want to compress it and then upload it. Any suggestions? I've tried using "Silicompressor" lib but it's also not working. I'm not using any MediaRecorder class therefore, I'm unable to use android video compression sdk I guess. I read about using FFMPEG but it's too hard for me to understand as I'm a newbiee. Please help. If anyone here know some easy way to do this please guide me. Thanks in advance.
dependency in my gradel file for silicompressor- 
compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
I'm not getting what to put at destinationUriString and how to proceed.
`

```
private void startRecording() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        file+= "/Videos.mp4";

    }
}

public void upLoadVideo() {
    //mProgress.setMessage("Your file's uploading... ");
   // mProgress.show();
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(this.getApplication()).compressVideo(file.toString(), destinationUriString);
        StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child(mUserId).child("video" + uuid + ".flv");

    riversRef.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
           //  mProgress.dismiss();
            Uri dUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            downloadUri = dUrl.toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alert();
        }
    });

}


public void alert() {


    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            VideoFragment.this).create();

    {
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Any requirments in mind?");
        alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                uploadbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadbutton);
                uploadbutton.setEnabled(false);
                uploadbuttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                uploadbuttonR.setEnabled(true);
                reqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reqButton);
                reqButton.setEnabled(true);
                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To add requirments Click Requiments", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //r= "yes";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
                downloadUriR="NULL";
                Upload user = new Upload("1001p","energysaving", downloadUri,downloadUriR);
                dataref.child(mUserId).push().setValue(user);
               // sendEmail();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThanksActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: use this library https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor

Comment: have you used it? come you please guide me how to use it?

Comment: Yes i had use this lib in my project and its working fine

Comment: Audio is removed in compressed video in this library...how to resolve this?